# Bulk Add Hyperlinks in Excel using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I currently am cycling through each excel cell using a ForEach-Object, but want to take advantage of the MS Excel 'Address' function to add 100's of hyperlinks at the same time.

Current format:

```
$hyperLinkRange | ForEach-Object {    
$hyperLinkRange.Hyperlinks.Add($ws.Cells.Item($_.Row,1), "\\path\$($_.Value2)","", "Click for $($_.Value2)")
}
```

Would like to use something similar to below, so not to loop through them all, but to add them all at the same time:

```
$hyperLinkRange.Hyperlinks.Add($hyperLinkRange.Cells, "\\path\$($($hyperLinkRange.Address($false,$false)).Value2)","", "Click for $($($hyperLinkRange.Address($false,$false)).Value2)")
```

I appreciate any and all help! Thanks!
-JFV